# Passing HTML table to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

using MVC;
passing a table of elements as a list from controller to razor view

```
<tr>
  <td> Select Account  </td>
  <td> Select LOB</td>
  <td onclick="RemoveRow(this)"> <i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i></td>
 <td><input name="TLAccountIds.Index" value="0" autocomplete="off" type="hidden"></td>
  <td><input name="TLSPVAssignedAccounts[0].AccountId" value="0" type="text"> </td>
 <td><input name="TLSPVAssignedAccounts[0].LOBId" value="0" type="text"</td> 
</tr>
```

then adding by JQuery more rows as below:

```
 <tr>
    <td id="1">TE</td><td id="3">TE-Inbound</td>
    <td onclick="RemoveRow(this)"> <i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i>  </td>
    <td <input name="TLSPVAssignedAccounts.Index" value="1" type="hidden"></td> 
    <td> <input id="TLSPVAssignedAccounts[1].AccountId" name="TLSPVAssignedAccounts[1].AccountId" value="1" type="text"> </td> 
    <td> <input id="TLSPVAssignedAccounts[1].LOBId" name="TLSPVAssignedAccounts[1].LOBId" value="3" type="text"> </td>
</tr>
```

when submitting to form the JQuery made only is sent to controller

Can someone please tell me why and what can i do to send all tbl to controller

**Noting that** when only exists html row without jquery appened rows, the html row is seen by controller inside the list

Comment: perhaps I am not understanding parts of how I'm assuming C#.NET works, but you should just be able to use jquery to serialize the form that this is all in and send the data to an end point.

Comment: using the browsers developer tools i see the whole table with all its rows (recieved from controller or dynamically added by jquery )but when i press submit only the jquery made rows which are serialized appear in the controller

Comment: i see, i had misinterpreted that line. what code are you using to send it? is it just `$(this).serialize()`?

Comment: to send data from razor view to controller
 im using submit button (HTML.beginform) and passing the table as a list (a property in ViewModel)

Comment: For a start `name="TLAccountIds.Index"` does not match your collection property - its `name="TLSPVAssignedAccounts.Index"` (as per the dynamic row your adding)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yessssss that was it ! you saved my day thank you now all the rows are seen by the controller